# Git Setup - New User on old PC

Tags: git, git-config

I've taken ownership of a PC that was a former employee. Git was installed and the .config file etc is therefore under the former employees directory under ./Users.

Do I need to do a brand new install of MySysGit or can I run some commands to get git configured to look at my directory under ./Users/MyAccountName?

Comment: I'd always reinstall a PC when it was used by someone else before. You can never know if he has some porn lying around or what malware he accidentally installed while using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy the former's employee `.gitconfig` to your Users' directory, and edit it with a text editor to give it your idenntity (name and email)

Comment: Thanks Charles, didn't realise it would be so simple.